# Database connection in hostgator

Tags: php, database, connection

I am new to the world of hosting websites and those stuff, 
so if anyone could help me on this matter i would really appreciate it.

I've created a website using Wampserver and it worked well but when i uploaded it to the Hostgator, the connection setup was different and am not sure if i did everything fine or not.

mainly the database is a collection of pictures and when i am trying to access those pictures it says "Cannot load image".
I am not sure if the issue from the connection file or something else

the following is the code of the connection file:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$databasename = 'ahmed_BLK360';
$username = 'ahmed_ahmed';
$password = '*********';
$con = mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$databasename","$username","$password");

// Check connection
if(isset($_POST['ImageName']))
{
    $image = $_POST['ImageName'];

$q1 = "SELECT * FROM panomarker where IMAGE_NAME ='$image'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$q1);
// a try to have the table as json file
if($result)
{
$Json_array =  array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $Json_array[] = $row;

}

//print_r($Json_array);
echo json_encode($Json_array);
}
else
{
    echo "it is not existed";
}


}


?>
```

is the connection code correct, and if so, why i could not access the images on the database?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Done

Comment: Your hosting provider should have provided you with this data (host, user, password, database name). What does it say?

Comment: Yes and i have inserted them as they provided me.
I am not getting any error message, but i could not load the images which are on the database.

Comment: Check the output of `mysqli_error($con)`  after making the query.

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean, should i do some changes in the code?